# PHP Mail Send when using a tag

Tags: php, newline, sendmail

PHP mail sending problem when using a tag, it doesn't come to new line.
HERE is my code having same problem

```
$subject = 'Watch Out Our Colorful Web Design Presentation';
$headers = "From: " . $email . " \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: test@test.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = "Watch Out Our Colorful Web Design Presentation.\r\n";
$message .= "<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>CLICK HERE</a>\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Mail send successfully but having problem in \r\n. It doesn't take new line. I tried br tag too. But it goes in junk mail.

Comment: I think `/r/n` ignored because content-type is `text/html`. Set Content-Type as `text/plain` but HTML tags won't work

Comment: I need text/html because I have to place a tag in it. If I remove a tag then it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

You're sending a HTML email. This means that you should be using HTML instead of newlines. To avoid having your emails placed in the junk folder, you should read some of the [many Stackoverflow topics on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mail%20php%20junk).

Comment: Actually, I sent mail many times But never occurred this type of problem. It might be because of I am using **a tag** in sending mail

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `<br>` tag for new line.

You can't use `\n` for new line for html printing.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=9542

Comment: I didn't mean in the html i meant in the headers. Sorry for not explaining it so well

Comment: I also tried this, but it shows in browser with a new line, but not work while sending mail

Comment: @MohamedHassan: Thank you it works now, But having problem that Mail has in new line, but it goes in junk folder.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to be using HTML line breaks `<br />` if you are sending an e-mail with `Content-Type: text/html`. The newlines/carriage returns will be interpreted in the source of the message as line breaks but they will probably not be rendered as HTML.

When sending e-mail from PHP I would always suggest using an e-mail class rather than PHP's native mail functions.

I tend to use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org). It has the advantage that all mail headers are sanitized and escaped to avoid header injection exploits that could potentially fire out spam through your script. Also it's easier to use a variety of e-mail transports. There's also a great decorator plugin which can send thousands of messages with customised strings, useful for doing things like "Dear {first_name} {surname}" or customised unsubscribe/tracking links.

Here's some sample code for SwiftMailer just in case you are interested...

```
// START SWIFTMAILER
require_once($swiftmailer_path);
$swift_transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance($sendmail_cmd);
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($swift_transport);
$swift_msg = Swift_Message::newInstance($swift_transport);
$swift_msg->setMaxLineLength(150);
$swift_msg->setFrom( array('NoReply@domain.com' => 'MyWebsiteName'));
$swift_msg->addTo($user);
$swift_msg->setSubject($subject);
$swift_msg->setBody($msg_html, 'text/html');
$swift_msg->addPart($msg_txt, 'text/plain');

// SEND E-MAIL
if ($swift_result = $swift->send($swift_msg)) {
    // SENT SUCCESSFULLY
} else {
    // ERROR - E-MAIL NOT SENT
}
```

Comment: Not Work for me, Because i am not using any classes at here.